# To find infimum and supremum of the set $S=\{\sin x-2\cos x;x \in R\}$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the infimum and supremum of the set $$S=\{\sin x-2\cos x;x \in R\}$$

I know that infimum of $S$ is the greatest member ,say $l$ ,of the set of all lower bounds of $S$ and supremum of $S$ is the smallest member $k$ of the set of all upper bounds of $S$.

I could calculate it easily in case of  real sequences but how do I proceed in this case?

The answer is given as $lub=-\sqrt 5 $  and $glb=\sqrt 5$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know that $$a\sin x +b\cos x = A\sin (x+\varphi)$$ where $A=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ and some $\varphi$. Thus the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can write $\sin x -2\cos x$ can be written in the form of $r\sin(x + \theta)$ where $r = \sqrt{1^2+2^2} = \sqrt 5$.

But, note that: $-1 \leq \sin(x+\theta) \leq 1 $, hence, $$-\sqrt 5 \leq \sin x - 2\cos x \leq \sqrt 5$$

Answer (score 0):

By C-S $$|\sin{x}-2\cos{x}|\leq\sqrt{(1^2+(-2)^2)(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)}=\sqrt5.$$
The equality occurs for $(1,-2)||(\sin{x},\cos{x}),$